# Помогите составить легкую программу на C++

Tags: c++

Дано натуральное число N (N<=10<sup>9</sup>). Определить сколько раз в нем встречается последняя цифра (без учета последней цифры).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
    int N,i,c;
    scanf ("%d", &N);
    i=0;
    c=N%10;
    while (N%10 >= 0)
    {
        N=N%10; 
        i++;
    }
    printf ("%d", i);
}
```

Программа зацикливается. Почему?

Comment: а проблема то в чём?

Comment: зацикливается программа

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
 int N,i,c;
 scanf ("%d", &N);
 i=0;
 c=N%10;
 while (N%10 >= 0)
 {
  N=N%10; 
  i++;
 }
 printf ("%d", i);
}

Comment: `N=N%10` нужно делить, а не остаток брать

Answer (score 4):

```
cin >> n;
int last = n%10;
n /= 10;
int count = 0;
while(n)
{
    if (n%10 == last) count++;
    n /= 10;
}
cout << count;
```

Где-то так... Если вы имеете в виду, что в числе 1254423452331212 последняя цифра встречается 4 раза.

Ваша программа не может не зацикливаться, так как с какого-то момента переменная цикла не меняется (когда становится одной цифрой, `N%10` равно `N`), и условие остается истинным...

Comment: Спасибо, как думаете, Дев си++ примет?

Comment: @vp_arth А об ошибке в тот момент, когда я писал ответ, спрошено еще не было :) Когда спросили - я ответил. Вы зря спешите...

Comment: Думаю, что да - тут нет ничего выходящего за рамки C++ еще прошлого века.

Comment: Благодарю, чуть-чуть поправил программу: #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
 int N,i,c;
 scanf ("%d", &N);
 i=0;
 c=N%10;
 while( N>0)
{
    if (N%10 == c) i++;
    N /= 10;
}
 printf ("%d", i);
}

Comment: Это очень хорошо! раз вы разобрались сами - теперь это запомнится куда лучше.

Comment: @Harry а зачем вообще тут число?) читали бы как строку да и ладно.

Comment: @pavel Неспортивно как-то :) Хотя можно вообще в один проход - читать по одному символу слева направо и выставлять 10 счетчиков, а по окончании считывания выдать значение нужного счетчика :) Эх, надо будет в следующий раз такое решение предложить...

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> N=N%10;
> ```

В этом месте должно быть деление, а не остаток.
Зацикливается из-за того, что остаток от деления на 10 никогда не меняется.

PS: А ещё код не дописан - не хватает собственно проверки на равенство последней цифре.